# How to properly configure a web application instance with autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Last day I wanted, according to AWS recommendations, put my ec2 instance inside of an autoscaling group. I created my ec2 instance by using the standard linux AMI instance and then I installed a full LAMP server.
The next morning I tried accessing my apache and guess what? My LAMP wasn't there anymore! Everything was wiped away.

I guess this is because, for some reason, the autoscaling group deleted my instance and recreated it vanilla.

Now I still want to autoscale my instance but, of course, I want to keep my LAMP and the stored data.
So here's my questions:

1. How to create a customized image starting from my actual instance?
2. Would it be correct to create the mysql DB using AWS RDS so to not keep it linked to my instance?Is it more or less expensive than dedicating a EBS storage?
3. I also want to keep my /var/www/html data somewhere shared between instances: while it is true that, on production, I won't update those files often it is also true that I don't want to lose them just because the autoscaling resets my instance state. I also don't want to re-create an image each time I update said files... What's the best way?Maybe an s3 bucket? Or, still, an EBS storage shared between instances?

Comment: Scalability is not a simple thing to setup and maintain. For relational databases it's even more difficult, I think. Why don't you use Elastic Beanstalk or maybe move to a serverless artchitecture using AWS Lambda and DynamoDB? It will be much easier, removing the infrastructure hassle and let you focus on your application.

Comment: I'd like to do so but I was imposed to use drupal CMS and it requires a RDBMS..

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk should solve scalability in the server side. There are lots of resources on the web, see [Drupal climbs the AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://peterjlord.co.uk/article/drupal-climbs-aws-elastic-beanstalk) and also [Deploying a High-Availability Drupal Website with an External Amazon RDS Database to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hadrupal-tutorial.html). On the DB side, you'll want to look into [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/aurora/serverless/). It's still in closed beta, though.

Comment: Anyway, how much traffic is expected for the application you're developing? Are you sure you cannot handle with a singe server with more RAM and CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the reason that your "LAMP [server] wasn't there anymore" was because the web server failed [health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/healthcheck.html) and was terminated and replaced by AutoScaling.

Elastic Beanstalk would be a good way to manage some of the complexity here. If that's not an option then you should read up on AutoScaling, ALB, and health checks.

In response to your specific questions:

1. you can create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from an instance. When you, or AutoScaling, launch a new instance from that AMI, you can get the instance up to date by [running a script in userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)
2. move the DB from the web/app server to RDS, or to a DB server that you manage yourself
3. maintain the html/js/css etc. in S3 and sync them to your web server periodically (there are other options, but that's simple)

Comment: I'll start looking at the 1. For the 2 you say that it's less expensive than a separate disk?

Comment: RDS is not a disk. It's a managed database service. You could probably manage your own DB server on EC2 for less upfront money than RDS, but you then have to do a lot of management tasks that RDS does for you. Decide how much you value your time, compare the costs, and see which option is better for you.